# Looping through DataSet table

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, visual-studio-2012, wpfdatagrid

I have installed VS 2012 after many years using VS 2010 and I can't even manage to loop through table rows anymore (which was a doddle before) and it is absolutely critical to my project.

I tried many ways of calling `DataGrid.Rows` but that is no longer available to users at all, so I am trying to find a work around.

Here's and here is what i have come up with , but the second part is just not working for me.

```
foreach (TableRow row in MyDatabaseDataSet.Tables["Table1"].Rows)
{
//Pesky lengthy non-working code supposed to generate 
//controls dependent on row cell value
}
```

Just to make things simpler (the code not working is just so lengthy it would be counter-constructive to post it here. Instead let's try and get a messagebox to show the value of the cell in the 2nd column of the row looked at.

But nothing does it.

i tried many many ways that i could think of including:

```
MessageBox.Show(row.Cells[2].Value);
MessageBox.Show(row.Cells[2].Text);
```

But it just will not work for me at all!

Doesn't even want to run the project at all.

How can I loop through all the rows in a `DataTable` or even a `Datagrid`?

PS: I forgot to mention but I also added the Load Data segment in the code prior to the foreach statement written above.

Comment: `DataTable.Rows` returns a `DataRowCollection` which contains `DataRows` not `TableRows`.

Comment: When you say "it's not working", and you don't tell us what that means (like you did twice), it's pretty much meaningless. If "it doesn't work", tell us in what way it doesn't work. Does it not compile? Does it cause an exception at runtime? Is there an error message? If so, what **exactly** does it say? It's much easier if you provide us the info, since you already have it right in front of you, instead of making us guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe i'm overlooking something simple, but [`DataTable.Rows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx) returns a [`DataRowCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which contains [`DataRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) not [`TableRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.tablerow.aspx).

So instead of

```
foreach (TableRow row in MyDatabaseDataSet.Tables["Table1"].Rows)
{
    // ...
}
```

this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in MyDatabaseDataSet.Tables["Table1"].Rows)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable.Rows` returns an instance of `DataRowCollection`, which contains `DataRow` objects, not `TableRow`

```
foreach( DataRow row in MyDatabaseDataSet.Tables["Table1"].Rows)
{
   // code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you. the answer is indeed DataRow instead of tabel row and to get the cell value just do:
messagebox.show(row.Field<string>("Columnname"))